# N-Patches of Bézier triangles with arbitrary degree

Tags: algorithm, graphics, surface, cad

For creating N-Patches of Bézier triangles with degree 3 (cubic), the control points are computed as follows:

[image]

But how do you compute control points for N-Patches of an arbitrary degree Bézier triangles? I want to create an algorithm, where you input a degree and the appropriate control points of a specified triangle vertices with corresponding normals are computed, but have implemented it just for the degree 3, using the formulas above.

Comment: Consider supporting http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985/computer-graphics.

Comment: Then you will need more data at the triangle's vertices other than position and normal. For example, if you want to go with degree 5 Bezier triangular patch, you probably need the first derivatives and the 2nd derivatives at the vertices.